# Why std::basic_ostream has both free and member operator<<?

Tags: c++

The title is my question. [basic_ostream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream) has both types of the insertion operator. The free [operator<<](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) is for chars and the member [operator<<](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) is for non char data.

Why is there a need to implement some as free function and others as member function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They could have all been implemented as free functions, and that is the preferred usage nowadays. Back when iostreams was created, they might have been trying to keep the overload set small.

There's a lot of weirdness in the iostreams and locale libraries; they should not be used as model desgins.

In C++98, you can do

```
int i;
std::ifstream( "data" ) >> i;
```

but you cannot do

```
std::string s;
std::ifstream( "data" ) >> s;
```

The temporary `ifstream` object will not bind to a reference parameter, but it will bind to `this`.

That's pretty much the only difference between the member and non-member versions. C++11 smoothed over this difference with rvalue references. (There's also the way you would call them without operator overloading, like `cin.operator >> ( i )`, but nobody ever does that.)